# BehaviorSubject subscription is called twice

Tags: angular

I have two component that communicate using a `BehaviorSubject`. Here's a simple reprodution:

DashboardComponent:

```
this.service.setCheckIsTrue();
```

Service:

```
private $checkIsTrue = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
public checkIsTrueEvent = this.$checkIsTrue.asObservable();

public setCheckIsTrue(){
    this.$checkIsTrue.next(true);
}
```

Other component:

```
 this.composerService.checkIsTrueEvent
      .takeWhile(() => this.isAlive)
      .subscribe( res => {
        if(!!res && res){
          console.log("fired"); // <-- called twice
        }
      });
```

I have others BS that works prefectly fine, so I inspected the code and the function `setCheckIsTrue()` is called once. I could solve this problem using some `rxjs` operator, but it's not a real solve. Anyone has an idea about that happening?

Comment: show code where you are using `setCheckIsTrue()`

Comment: Is in the constructor

Comment: Ok, use a Subject and not Behavior subject. The behavior subject is doing exactly what the documentation says it does.

Answer (score 4):

When this happens to me I thrash about a bit until I realize that I've forgotten to unsubscribe in the component's ngOnDestroy().  Give that a try. :)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I used takeWhile operator to unsubscribe. I solved few months after asking this question (randomly) discovering that the service was provided in two different modules.

Comment: Ha, should have looked at this before adding my answer. Yes, this was my problem. Not removing old subscriptions on navigating away from a component. Going back to the page and initialising another instance of the component added another subscription so I got multiple subscription calls on each next().

Answer (score 1):

use condition

```
this.composerService.checkIsTrueEvent.takeWhile(() => this.isAlive).subscribe( res => {if('undefined' != typeof res){  
          console.log("fired");// <----called once }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `BehaviorSubject` with initial value `null` which will notify all subscriber for first time. Then you setting the next value by `this.$checkIsTrue.next(true);` which is triggering the next notification.

If you are not bothered about the last value then you can simply use `Subject` instead of `BehaviorSubject`.

```
private $checkIsTrue = new Subject<any>();
```

Comment: Problem persist, sadly

Comment: Can you comment  `this.$checkIsTrue.next(true);` and check how many time it calls.

Comment: It solved it self in a random way. Don't really know how, I didn't change anything

Comment: You mean it is working fine with `BehaviorSubject ` ?

Comment: Things dont just solve themselves. @SunilSingh got it with the usage of `Subjects` vs BS, so did you change something or discover something?

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience most of the time it depends on where you are going to call the function. Most of the time it will call twice and generate an error (sometimes) if you are using calling it in the **constructor**. You can call it inside **ngOnInit()**. So it won't generate any errors and won't call the function twice.

Also, I tried this one with **BehaviorSubject** and **Subject** noting changed. So you can try the above.

Comment: Thank's for the reply, as I said in one comment above the error was solved fixing the fact that I had provided the service in two different modules that exists at runtime in the given time

Comment: @Jacopo Sciampi Thank you, I also did the same mistake